# how to get the values entered from the datagrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, datagrid, windows

i have a datagrid. which display some values which is already inserted and that is fetched from database.but from the datagrid i need to insert the values to database. how to find in which row a new record get inserted and to pass all the values to database

any idea???

How to get the row before last row index or any identification..

Answer (score 0):

See this
http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=13402